# Does anyone have the [ Leap Motion Android SDK ] copy?

Tags: android, sdk

Does anyone have the Leap Motion Android SDK copy? Doesn't matter of its version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Leap Motion Android SDK is in private alpha, and may not be shared without violating our SDK terms. Anyone who wants to try the alpha may apply here; however, we don't have an ETA for when it will be shared: https://docs.google.com/a/ocuspec.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfiuluXiq5vaiIJBiAnUiNjR5OgpvXWiZNhU_JPdUwXSUcnkw/viewform

Once the SDK is ready for public beta, it will be made available for everyone.

Comment: Android SDK is still not available for public. Do you have any idea when would it be released?